# shell script to kill the process listening on port 3000?

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, kill

I want to define a bash alias named `kill3000` to automate the following task:

```
$ lsof -i:3000

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    13402 zero    4u  IPv4 2847851      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)

$ kill -9 13402
```

Comment: Why do you want an alias and not a bash function?

Comment: I would make a function which first do a `kill -TERM` then do a `kill -KILL` because it is un-proper to kill processes without giving them the opportunity to terminate properly...

Comment: @SteveChambers how is this a duplicate when it was written before the answer it is linked to? Absurd...

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
alias kill3000="fuser -k -n tcp 3000"
```

Comment: The reason I chose this as the answer is because I later found that `lsof -i:3000` can bring back multiple processes when I access the server in the web browser (e.g.):

`ruby      587 zero   10u  IPv4 2239530      0t0  TCP localhost:3000->localhost:45341 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 26843 zero   63u  IPv4 2238948      0t0  TCP localhost:45337->localhost:3000 (ESTABLISHED)`

I found that, `fuser -n tcp 3000` most accurately brings back the original process and so, probably would be the most reliable to use.

Comment: One thing I noticed was that fuser doesn't differentiate between local and remote connections - so I think if you ever had a process connected to a remote port 3000 it'd get killed too. For what it's worth.

Comment: Note that `fuser` sends a SIGKILL by default. You can tell it to use a different signal with for instance: `fuser -k -TERM -n tcp 3000`.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me. After I issue the command and I do netstat -tulpn | grep 8001 , I still get the pid of the process. I am trying to kill a tcp port listening process - fuser -k -n tcp 8001

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX: 
`Unknown option: k`
`Unknown option: n`

Comment: Juans-MacBook-Pro:ui-app jjalonso$ fuser -k -n tcp 9009
Unknown option: k
Unknown option: n
fuser: [-cfu] file ...
 -c file is treated as mount point
 -f the report is only for the named files
 -u print username of pid in parenthesis

Comment: It doesnt work for me either. I have a nodemon process running on 8080. If I open new terminal and run this, it gives me a pid, but when I go to chrome, I can still see the API on 8080 port. Not to mention the nodemon process doesnt get killed either in previous terminal.

Answer (score 76):

Try this:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i:3000 -t)
```

The -t flag is what you want: it displays PID, and nothing else.

#### Update

In case the process is not found and you don't want to see error message:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i:3000 -t) 2> /dev/null
```

Assuming you are running bash.

#### Update

[Basile's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168392/shell-script-to-kill-the-process-listening-on-port-3000/9168553#comment11538126_9168553) is excellent: we should first try to terminate the process normally will `kill -TERM`, if failed, then `kill -KILL` (AKA `kill -9`):

```
pid=$(lsof -i:3000 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
```

You might want to make this a bash function.

Comment: I would suggest `kill -TERM` first, then `kill -KILL`

Comment: I would also use `tcp` as in `lsof -i tcp:3000` in scripts to be more precise.

Comment: This is not working if i execute from a remote server. lsof not providing any output. ssh dbbuser@ipaddr 'kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:2900)'

Answer (score 12):

Another option using using the original `lsof` command:

```
lsof -n -i:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq | xargs kill -9
```

If you want to use this in a shell script, you could add the `-r` flag to `xargs` to handle the case where no process is listening:

```
... | xargs -r kill -9
```

Comment: Don't forget the -r on xargs. :p

Comment: synthesizerpatel: I personally don't too much care about that `not enough arguments` message. It's not like `kill` would go crazy and shoot your init process if it doesn't get input (correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: If you have something like this in a shell script with 'set -e', or '#!/usr/bin/bash -e', the failure of kill would cause the entire script to fail. My motto is: succeed quietly if you can, fail elegantly if you have to - but always return a useful exit code.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: True, but if I'd only use that from the command line ("automate the routine"), I'd actually like to see whether something was killed or not, and that's a simple way to achieve this :) Inside a shell script I'd probably add `-r` or use `|| true`, so I could at least see the error message.

Comment: Heh. I only ran across this because I tested the lsof version.. If you have a service that binds to multiple interfaces, the lsof method will yield two identical PIDs as well. I'm not picking on you - I swear to god. Never saw the lsof -i:NNNN flag before. Oh, the other thing I'd suggest is '-n' so that lsof doesn't try to reverse-lookup any of the hosts.

Comment: @synthesizer: Thanks, I'll add `-n`, `uniq`, and (optinally) `-r` :P

Comment: One more optimization I think.. lsof -t -i4TCP:8090 -sTCP:LISTEN, which can be further tuned using the IP address, like so lsof -t -i4TCP@localhost:8090 -sTCP:LISTEN. That should also guarantee only one result.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: Thanks, but that's a bit too verbose IMHO and doesn't really improve functionality very much (after all, I don't know exactly what OP wants, I basically copy-and-pasted his already known-to-work command line).

Answer (score 5):

`fuser -k 3000/tcp` should also work

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
alias kill3000="lsof -i:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fuser -n tcp 3000
```

Will yield the output of

```
3000/tcp:     <$pid>
```

So you could do:

```
fuser -n tcp 3000 | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -r kill
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this usage of `awk` is unnecessary and fails anyway. Playing with the `fuser` output, I eventually realized that what appears as the first column is actually stderr.