# How to deal with port occupied even though Websphere process removed?

Tags: windows, linux, websphere, aix

have you ever got the situation some websphere used port occupied even after that websphere process has been stopped or killed?
      as for such issue, how to fix it? well, i know it can be gone after server reboot. but you know, it's not the best one and we can't do it often since it's SERVER stuff.

thanks in advance

Comment: oh,that's my fault. it's ok now! Please help me out, master. @rkosegi

Comment: I usually "kill -9" any Java processes over 300MB when I'm looking to do that...

Comment: Your issue isn't WebSphere related. BTW, a solution to your real problem was already addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168392/shell-script-to-kill-the-process-listening-on-port-3000)

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain it's WebSphere holding the port? If you've stopped all the WebSphere processes, especially if you've stopped them normally, I can't imagine that it is still holding the port.

On AIX, you can see which process is holding the port with [the combination of netstat and rmsock described here](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264632) (or [if you have lsof installed, that's even easier](http://portal2portal.blogspot.com/2011/06/aide-memoire-remembering-how-to.html).)

Comment: yeah, i'm pretty much sure it's the Websphere holding the port since the port is 9080 used as WC_Default by Websphere. Yes, it's very weird indeed. the process gone but the port still be holding there.

Comment: Even if you're pretty sure, you should use the steps describe to be certain. Then if we know it's WebSphere, we can proceed from there.