# Stop laravel server with command line interface

Tags: laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

I just tried to automate the laravel process like(Start, Stop) in shell scripts.
To start the laravel server, I use php artisan serve in the shell file.

I tried to stop the laravel server using command. But I was wonder, I didnt 
    see any commands to stop the server. I used to Ctl+C to stop the server or to close the command prompt.

1.Any laravel commands to stop the server ?

2. I have started the laravel server using shell file, which exits after starting.

How can I stop them now ? I dont have any command prompts running this process to exit the server.

Comment: Locate the php process running artisan and kill it. If you are on windows system Ctrl + Shift + ESC => locate process => Right click => kill process

Comment: any other solutions tony vincent

Comment: u can use something like php killall from the terminal

Comment: If you're running it on a port and you're running a 'nix system, you could do something like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168392/shell-script-to-kill-the-process-listening-on-port-3000

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can kill the port

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:port_number)
```

**Like if it is running on 8000, you can do below**

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
```

If above not worked (because frozen or unresponsive process may not respond), add parameter `-9` to kill command like this:

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
```

Answer (score 6):

Easier and you can view all processes about artisan :)

```sh
ps aux | grep artisan
# get the PID from the list
kill <PID NUMBER>
```

Comment: FYI, `pkill` does pattern searches, `pkill -f artisan` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try
killall -9 php
Then
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
Then
php artisan serve

Comment: Never use `-9` unless it's absolutely necessary and other options have been exhausted.